# Cannot find class in another file

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol

I've looked at answers other users have asked for similar question and still can't figure out why I'm getting can't find symbol errors for two classes I've created.

My dir looks like this

```
StacksAndQueuesProblems/threestacks
```

inside the `threestacks` directory, I have the following `.java` files:

```
FullStackException.java
fixedMultiStack.java
```

From the `StacksAndQueuesProblems` directory I tried to execute `javac threestacks/*.java`
however I get the following error:

```
    threestacks/fixedMultiStack.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
            throw FullStackException("ERR: That stack is full!");
                  ^
```

FullStackException.java

```
package threestacks;

public class FullStackException extends Exception {

    public FullStackException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

fixedMultiStack.java

```
package threestacks;

class fixedMultiStack {

    private int numberOfStacks = 3;
    private int stackCapacity;
    private int[] values;
    private int[] sizes;

    public fixedMultiStack(int stackCapacity) {
        this.stackCapacity = stackCapacity;
        values = new int[stackCapacity * numberOfStacks]; // Holds all 3 stacks
        sizes = new int[numberOfStacks+1]; // Holds the number of items in each stack
    }

    /* push value onto stack */
    public void push(int stackNum, int value) throws FullStackException {
        /* check if we have space on the stack for the element */
        if (isFull(stackNum)) {
            throw FullStackException("ERR: That stack is full!");
        }
        /* increment stack pointer and then insert the value */
        sizes[stackNum]++; // Increment the number of items for that stack
        values[indexOfTop(stackNum)] = value; // Insert the value into the array
    }

    /* Pop item from the stack */
    public void pop(int stackNum) {
        if (isEmpty(stackNum)) {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        /* Retreive the value and decrement the stack pointer */
        int topIndex = indexOfTop(stackNum);
        int value = values[topIndex]; //Get top
        values[topIndex] = 0; // Clear
        sizes[stackNum]--; // Decrement the size of the stack
    }

    /* Return top element */
    public int peek(int stackNum) {
        if (isEmpty(stackNum)) {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        int topIndex = indexOfTop(stackNum);
        int value = values[topIndex];
        return value;
    }

    /* Return if stack is empty */
    public boolean isEmpty(int stackNum) {
        return sizes[stackNum] == 0;
    }

    /* Return if stack is full */
    public boolean isFull(int stackNum) {
        return sizes[stackNum] == stackCapacity;
    }

    /* Returns index of top of stack */
    public int indexOfTop(int stackNum) {
        return ((stackNum -1) * stackCapacity + sizes[stackNum] - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `throw new SomethingException("some String");`? You're forgetting the `new` it seems.

Comment: Voting to close as more of a typographical error.

Comment: Thank's for your response but does that merit a downvote?

Comment: Yes, on further thought, you're right, it doesn't. Down-vote removed. However the error message is telling you exactly where the problem is, and so in the future, you will want to proof-read the involved lines more carefully so as to avoid similar careless errors. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a compilation error in the file fixedMultiStack.java. It should be

```
throw new FullStackException("ERR: That stack is full!");
```